# VB.net WPF Accessing Variables called in Application Startup

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm writing a program which Starts up an Excel file in the application's startup event handler:

```
' Application.xaml.vb
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Class Application
    ' Application-level events, such as Startup, Exit, and DispatcherUnhandledException
    ' can be handled in this file.

    ' Startup handler
    Public Sub Application_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        ' Initialise Excel
        Dim XLapp As Excel.Application
        Dim XLwb As Excel.Workbook
        Dim XLws As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim XLra As Excel.Range
        ' File and worksheet are opened here, using inputprompt to query user for the right sheet.
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now my question is, how do I access these variables (such as XLws) from MainWindow.xaml.vb? Normally you'd create a new object of the class but does this work with the application's startup handler? If so how do I get around the sender and e argument errors?

What I'm going for is that the application loads the large excel file at the startup, and then reads/writes to it on button_clicks.

Comment: You can't access those variables because they're locals.  If you want to access them outside that method then they must be declared outside the method.  Ideally, declare them as properties in that `Application` class and then access them via `My.Application` anywhere in your project.

Comment: I had no idea about properties yet since I'm still learning. This helped me out a lot, thank you